# Loading external files within a class/module

Tags: ruby, class, module, load

I have an external file: `path_to_external_file.rb` with some class definition:

```
class A
  some_definitions
end
```

And I want to load that within module `B` so that the class `A` defined above can be referred to as `B::A`. I tried:

```
class B
  load('path_to_external_file.rb')
end
```

but `A` is defined in the main environment, not in `B`:

```
A #=> A
B.constants # => []
```

How can I load external files within some class/module?

**Edit**
Should I read the external files as strings, and evaluate them within `Class.new{...}`, and `include` that class within `B`?

Comment: to what end?  Why can't you just use class A directly?  Are you getting some benefit from modularizing it?  `load` and `require` will not actually load a class into a module, they just load the source code, so your classes are defined exactly as they are in the file.  Not sure why you'd want to do this?

Comment: @brad Because these external files are to be written by users, and can be named arbitrary. If I define those classes within the main environment, they will mess up the naming space.

Comment: Beware of tampering with other namespaces via `ObjectSpace#each_object`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. At least using `load` or `require`, the Ruby files will always be evaluated in a top context.

You can work around that problem in two ways:

- Define `class B::A` directly (but you are probably trying to avoid that)
- Use `eval(File.read("path_to_external_file.rb"))` within your `B` class

**Edit:** Maybe, this library is interesting for you: https://github.com/dreamcat4/script/blob/master/intro.txt

Comment: There is an opening issue that seems to address it: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10320

Answer (score 3):

Generally, it's a bad idea to define a class as "class A" but then "magically" make it contained by module B. If you want to refer to class A as B::A, you should define it using either:

```
module B
  class A
    # contents
  end
end
```

or:

```
class B::A
  # contents
end
```

Otherwise anyone who reads your code will be confused. In this case, you don't gain anything in clarity, brevity, or convenience by using "tricks", so straightforward code is better. There is a lesson here: the metaprogramming features of Ruby are great, but there is no need to use them gratuitously. Only use them when you really gain something from doing so. Otherwise you just make your code hard to understand.

BUT, having read your comment, it looks like there is really a good reason to do something like this in your case. I suggest that the following solution would be even better than what you are envisioning:

```
m = Module.new
m.module_eval("class C; end")
m.constants
=> [:C]
m.const_get(:C)
=> #<Module:0xfd0da0>::C
```

You see? If you want a "guaranteed unique" namespace, you can use an anonymous module. You could store these modules in a hash or other data structure, and pull the classes out of them as needed. This solves the problem you mentioned, that the users of your app are going to be adding their own classes, and you don't want the names to collide.